# How to fetch the People picker values in custom edit form.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker

I have customized the sharepoint list Newfor/Editform/dispform.aspx pages with my custom page.

Below is the screenshot for the same.

In My custom for.aspx page i have 2 Sharepoint people picker controls

--> I was sucessfully able to add the users to the people picker in Newform.aspx page.
but when i click on Edit form.aspx page i am not sure how to fetch the people picker values entered by the user.

Note: I was sucessfully able to fetch the other data like Dropdown,datepicker,textbox like below on Load data()

Data type of the People picker in my content type is Peopleorgroup.
[image]

Code  which i have tried

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
              LoadData()
              }
        }
private void LoadData()
        {
            var list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[new Guid(Request.QueryString["list"])];
            var itemId = 0;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) == false)
            {
                int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out itemId);
            }
            if (itemId != 0)
            {
                var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
                ddlNotificationType.SelectedIndex = ddlNotificationType.Items.IndexOf(ddlNotificationType.Items.FindByText((listItem["NotificationType"] == null) ? string.Empty : listItem["NotificationType"].ToString()));
                txtTitle.Text = (listItem["Title"] == null) ? string.Empty : listItem["Title"].ToString();
                ddlTaskFrequency.SelectedIndex = ddlTaskFrequency.Items.IndexOf(ddlTaskFrequency.Items.FindByText((listItem["TaskFrequency"] == null) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(listItem["TaskFrequency"])));
                TStartDate.Text = (listItem["StartDate"] == null) ? string.Empty : listItem["StartDate"].ToString();
                ChkNoofDays.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean((listItem["DuedateChecked"] == null) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(listItem["DuedateChecked"]));
}
}


*/Button clicked is fired when saving an item*/
 protected void btnSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[new Guid(Request.QueryString["list"])];
            var itemId = 0;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) == false)
            {
                int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out itemId);
            }
            SPListItem listItem = null;
            if (itemId == 0)
            {
                listItem = list.AddItem();
            }
            else
            {
                listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
            }


            SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = GetPeopleFromPickerControl(userPicker, mySiteWeb);
            SPFieldUserValueCollection Backusercollection = GetPeopleFromPickerControl(pplBackup, mySiteWeb);
            String Notificationtype = Convert.ToString(ddlNotificationType.SelectedItem.Text);
            String TaskTitle = Convert.ToString(txtTitle.Text);
            String TaskFrequency = ddlTaskFrequency.SelectedItem.Text;
            String Startdate = Convert.ToString(TStartDate.Text);
            String DuedateChecked = Convert.ToString(ChkNoofDays.Checked);
            listItem["NotificationType"] = Notificationtype;
            listItem["Title"] = TaskTitle;
            listItem["PointOfContact"] = usercollection;
            listItem["BackupPointOfContact"] = Backusercollection;
            listItem["TaskFrequency"] = TaskFrequency;
            listItem["StartDate"] = Startdate;
            listItem["DuedateChecked"] = DuedateChecked;
            listItem["NoofDays"] = Noofdays;
            listItem["DueDate"] = Duedate; 
             listItem.Update();
            Context.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Guys I made it after scratching my head :-)... Thanks to Google

Below is the code in order to do the same.

```
 if (listItem["PointOfContact"] != null)
                {
                    char[] to_splitter = { ';' };
                    string to_list = listItem["PointOfContact"].ToString(); // Reads value stored in SPList. (i.e., "Domain\User1; Domain\User2")
                    string[] arr = to_list.Split(to_splitter);
                    string user = string.Empty;
                    System.Collections.ArrayList entityArrayList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
                    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i % 2) != 0)
                        {
                            user = arr[i].Substring(arr[i].IndexOf("#") + 1);
                            PickerEntity entity = new PickerEntity();
                            entity.Key = user;
                            entity = userPicker.ValidateEntity(entity);
                            entityArrayList.Add(entity);
                        }
                    }
                    userPicker.UpdateEntities(entityArrayList);
                }
```